# Processing regex-matching CSV records in python

Tags: python, regex, csv, match

I've tried (4 hrs spent reading docs, googling, ...) and it must be my brain so I'd appreciate any gentle nudge or proper kick in the right direction:

Got a `.csv` file, which I need to process:
only keep certain regex-matching lines (RE is `^[A-Z][A-Z];.*15%;`), then print out specific columns (say 1, 2, 13, 15 and 17). Very easy in shell (grep, awk), impossible (for me) in python.

This is the code I came up with so far:

```
import re
import csv
src="/Users/username/file.csv"
reg="^[A-Z][A-Z];.*15%;"
with open(src, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line=line.strip()
        match = re.match(reg,line.strip())
        if match:
            vat=csv.reader(line, delimiter=';')
            for r in vat:
                print r[0]
```

Contrary to my belief, csv module parses each character as record, not the entire line, hence the output is not field [0] of an array, but 1 character.

If I add print line after if match

```
if match:
    print line
```

the lines are printed correctly, hence my confusion - why does csv.reader not treat them as such?

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts - knowing python, the solution is extremely simple ;-)

PS: *bonus points if RE matching can be made on individual columns, i. e. only process line if column 1 matches [A-Z][A-Z] ignoring case and column 17 matches 15% - then print columns 1, 2, 13, 15 and 17.*

Comment: `csv.reader` iterate over the object you give it, then split it into a list of strings. You feed csv.reader with a line instead of a file. When you iterate over a line (which is a string) you get characters as _records_, when you iterate over a file you get lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(src, newline='') as file:
    r = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    for line in r:
        if len(line[0]) ==2 and line[0].isalpha() and line[16]=='15%':
            print(line) #Or whatever it is you want to do
```

No regex really necessary, but `r'[a-zA-Z]{2}'` could also work

Comment: Shoud be: `line[16]=='15%'` (syntax error). Can't edit this post directly, because "Edits must be at least 6 characters" ;)

Comment: thanks Patrick! That did the trick :-) much more elegant than mine (which isn't all that difficult) ;-)